# Capturing and saving objects coordinates with fabric js

Tags: html, extjs, fabricjs

I am working on an app where a user can create multiple boxes on a canvas, save the coordinates of each box(Top, Left, Width, Height) individually in database, and later retrieve them back on a canvas, whenever needed to update its position.
I am able to do all this, except updating the position of the box.

For eg. Lets say user selects "box1":
1) canvas.on('mouse:down', function (evt) { }); - gives the current coordinates for box1, that matches with the database entry.

2) canvas.on('object:modified', function (evt) { }); - gives the new coordinates for box1, that I can use to update the database fields.

The only problem is, if the user selects box1, drag it some where, drops it, and again drags it to a new position. I loose the original value (since he clicked mouse:down twice for box1), and thus not able to finally identify, which box was updated wrt database.

Below is the code snippet:

```
window.addRect = function() {
  var box = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    stroke: 'red',
    fill: 'rgba(255,0,0,.4)',
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
  });
  box.hasRotatingPoint = false;
  canvas.add(box);
}

canvas.on('object:modified', function (evt) {   // for updated values
var modifiedObject = evt.target;
console.log('modifiedObject: ' + modifiedObject.get('left'), modifiedObject.get('top'), modifiedObject.getScaledWidth(), modifiedObject.getScaledHeight());
});

canvas.on('mouse:down', function (evt) {  // for original values
var downObject = evt.target;
console.log('downObject: ' + downObject.get('left'), downObject.get('top'), downObject.getScaledWidth(), downObject.getScaledHeight());  });
```

Is there anything other than mouse:down and object:modified, that I can use? I am looking for a solution in Extjs.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for which you haven't used the serialization http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3#serialization? That would be the best way to do it. Is your backend running on NodeJS in that case you are able to load the JSON and do all sort of manipulations as FabricJS works in NodeJS as well.

Comment: Hi Adam, I am pretty new to fabric, and have used just the basic stuff so far. I will read about serialization in detail to see, if that works for me. No, I dont have NodeJs in my project. - Mili

Comment: So basically whatever you do with the canvas in FabricJS you can export toa JSON string. You save it in a database and load that JSON string again and everything will be like before.